# Why I get NaN instead of changing state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I wrote redux algorithm for updating money count on click. I don't know why but when I click on add or get cash button I see NaN.

This is my index.js where I describe reducer and actions

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import {createStore} from "redux";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const defaultState = {
  cash: 5,
}

const reducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_CASH":
      return {...state, cash: action.cash + action.payload}
    case "GET_CASH":
      return {...state, cash: action.cash - action.payload}
    default: 
      return state
  }
}

const store = createStore(reducer)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}> 
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This is my app.js where I implement logic of dispatch

```
import React from 'react';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const cash = useSelector(state=>state.cash)


const addCash = (cash) => {
  dispatch({type:"ADD_CASH", payload: cash})
}

const getCash = (cash) => {
    dispatch({type:"GET_CASH", payload: cash})
}

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{fontSize:"3rem"}}>{cash}</div>
      <div style={{display:"flex"}}>
        <button onClick={() => addCash(Number(prompt()))}>Пополнить счет</button>
        <button onClick={() => getCash(Number(prompt()))}>Снять со счета</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: `state.cash` not `action.cash`

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer function is getting cash=undefined, hence to solve this you have to add "state.cash" instead of "action.cash".
After applying changes, your reducer function of index.js will be:

```
const reducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_CASH":
      return {...state, cash: state.cash + action.payload}
    case "GET_CASH":
      return {...state, cash: state.cash - action.payload}
    default: 
      return state
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `action.cash` with `state.cash`. It might be the cause of the error you are getting.